# Handle Dynamic IP Addresses on Login

Tags: login, ip

Currently, it would appear that if a user is using a system with a dynamic IP address, they will be logged out every time the IP address changes. The "solution" that has most commonly been presented with this is to simply turn off the "require IP address at login" option. This seems silly to me, because requiring an IP address addresses several security issues. How can I resolve this issue without turning of the IP address requirement issue?

Comment: Surely an IP wouldn't change during a session?  So I assume you have auto-login set and are using from the frontend?  Change from Session to Cookies in Admin > System Preferences > Security and Session Preferences.

Comment: @PeterLewis IP addresses can change during a session, for instance someone using a work computer on a large network.

Comment: You can still change both frontend and control panel to use cookies instead of session, which doesn't rely on IP and you don't have to turn off "require IP". It's an old thread, but still valid: https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/195675/#926359